# Numpy dot product results in `IndexError: only integers, slices...`

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to compute the dot product of two arrays like so:

```
for i in range(self.v_theta['shape'].shape[0] - 1):
   for j in range(self.v_theta['shape'].shape[1] - 1):
       self.theta['shape'][i, j] = \
           self.ratings[:, i].dot(self.v_ksi[:, i, j])
```

but am getting the following error:

```
self.ratings[:, i].dot(self.v_ksi[:, i, j])
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I've checked the type of `i` and `j`, and they're definitely integers, and the colons are surely slices. I've also double checked the shapes of the arrays and the setup above is definitely legitimate for a dot product.

`self.ratings` and `self.v_ksi` are both of type `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the type of `self.ratings` and `self.v_ksi`?

Comment: @Aaron `numpy.ndarray` for both

Comment: as far as I can tell your problem must be elsewhere then because this is correct.. can you reproduce the problem with a smaller complete test script (that you could post all of)?

Comment: please try to provide a [mcve], in the optimal case it should be copy&paste-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the error is actually coming from this part of the code:

```
        self.theta['shape'][i, j] = \
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The error message just confusingly points to the last physical line of the logical line on which the error occurred.

Perhaps you meant `self.v_theta` instead of `self.theta`.